# Can LSTM solve the particular problem I currently have

Tags: python, keras, lstm

As far as I know, LSTM can do regression/classification analysis in terms of time series data.  I am wondering if

```
time  feature1 feature2 feature3 output
day1 ....................................
day2.....................................
day3....................................
day4...................................
day5...................................
...
...
day30.................................
```

Assume I got the data from experiment and totally collected 30 days' data with format shown above. Using LSTM I definitely can predict the output of 31 day as long as I obtain the input (feature 1 to 3 in this case) in day 31.  My question is if I miss the experimental input data from day 31 to 50 (too busy to do experiment), could I still use LSTM to predict the output of 51 days? (I may have time to do the experiment again in day 51 ^.^).

This problem essentially is unlike the stock prediction problem that can be typically analyzed by LSTM. Since in the stock prediction problem, the output in time t can be considered as the input in time t+1. However, in this particular problem, the input (feature 1 to 3) can not be directly linked to the output.

Anyone can help to clarify/solve?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you single layer perceptron. I have an example code. You can get it by [clicking here](https://github.com/alihakimtaskiran/not_tahmin_edici/blob/master/Not%20Tahmin%20Eden%20Model.ipynb)
[Architecture of model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzSOK.png)

First parameter is day and other parameters are state of occur of features. Model adjust the parameters to predict output correctly. 
    If you explain your problem with more detail, I can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do Multi-Horizon forecasting with LSTM. You can find a similar architecture by Amazon [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1711.11053.pdf).

PS: these type of questions seems more suitable for https://datascience.stackexchange.com.